# Arduino locks up

Tags: c++, embedded, arduino

The intention of the program below is to periodically output a dataframe on serial. The period is defined by a timed interrupt, every second.

The code worked on Arduino IDE version 0022, but on 1.0 I can't get it working. When using the timer routine and `maxFrameLength` is set to `0x40` or higher, the controller locks up. When using 0x39 or lower, the program keeps running (indicated by the flashing LED).

What's going wrong here and why? Is it a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

I'm  using http://code.google.com/p/arduino-timerone/downloads/detail?name=TimerOne-v9.zip for the timer routine on a Mega1280.

```
#include "TimerOne.h"

#define LED 13
#define maxFrameLength 0x40

boolean stateLED = true;
byte frame[ maxFrameLength ];

void sendFrame() {
  digitalWrite( LED , stateLED );
  stateLED = !stateLED;
  Serial.write( frame, maxFrameLength ); // ptr + bytes to send
}

void setup() {
  pinMode( LED , OUTPUT );
  Timer1.initialize( 1000000 );  // initialize timer1 with 1 second period
  Timer1.attachInterrupt( sendFrame );
  Serial.begin( 9600 );
};

void loop() {
};
```

Comment: What is the flow control setup on the serial port?  Hardware? Software? None?

Comment: Shouldn't you call `Serial.begin` before initialisng the timer?

Comment: @AlanStokes: Correct, but doesn't solve the issue. Thxn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of issues that may or may not be causing a problem, but it should be fixed in any case. These comments are general in nature; I am not familiar with Arduino or its library specifically.

It is almost certainly inappropriate to issue a `Serial.write()` call in an interrupt handler (ISR). If the Serial object is interrupt driven, it will have an associated buffer. If that buffer is not large enough to take all the data, the function may *block*, which is a *no no* in an interrupt handler. Moreover, if the timer interrupt is a higher priority that the serial interrupt, you will cause a deadlock when `Serial.write()` blocks. 0x40 (64 bytes) seems like a likely buffer size for serial output, so that is likely the primary cause. If you can increase the buffer size that may make it work, but it remains a bad idea to perform potentially blocking operations in an ISR.

Even if serial output is polled rather than interrupt driven, your interrupt handler will take rather long, which is also a bad idea, but probably not the issue in this case, but at *9600,n,8,1*, 64 characters will take 67 milliseconds to clear the transmit register.

`stateLED` and `frame` are shared variables (between interrupt and main contexts) and should therefore be declared [volatile](http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/beginner-s-corner/4023801/Introduction-to-the-Volatile-Keyword).

It is not shown in your fragment how and where `frame` is updated, but since the interrupt will occur asynchronously, any update to `frame` should be in a *[critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section)* - with at least the timer1 interrupt disabled.

---

**Update**

In the light of A.H.'s response I downloaded the source code and took a look. `Serial` is a static object of class `HardwareSerial` defined in \arduino-1.0\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino\hardwareSerial.cpp/.h. The transmit buffer length is indeed 64 bytes, and the `HardwareSerial::write()` function does "busy-wait" if the buffer is full.  You will need to modify and re-build the source to extend the buffer or add a non-blocking version of `write()`.

This is however certainly the cause of the lock-up - the buffer will never empty because the transmit interrupt cannot be serviced while the timer1 interrupt is running.

Comment: "It is not shown in your fragment how and where frame is updated," I tried to find the smallest piece of code with wich I can reproduce the problem and I it turned out unnecessary to add that piece of the code. You make a valid point about disabling the interrupts for Timer1. I need to figure out the 'volatile' part too, I remember reading about it, but I'm not sure if it is supported by Arduino.

Comment: @jippie: The word [volatile](http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/beginner-s-corner/4023801/Introduction-to-the-Volatile-Keyword) in my answer is a link to an embedded.com article on the subject. Note that I have changed the link in the edit to the article I had originally intended but could not find at the time.  So if you followed it before, take another look.

Comment: @jippie: A.H.'s answer shows that the 1.0 behaviour is as I suggested in the second paragraph and was previously as in teh third.  Both are undesirable behaviour - an ISR *busy-waiting*, or *blocking*. The new library has not so much *broken* your code as exposed an existing flaw in a more visible fashion.

Comment: Don't know where I read it, but a little while ago I read that Arduino's serial buffer was 128 bytes. That must have been documentation to an old version. Anyway, this update looks like pin pointing the problem and at least I now know why my code fails and in what direction I need to rethink my design.

Comment: @Jippie:  I believe that prior to 1.0 only the receive was buffered and that buffer was 128 bytes.  In the 1.0 code both Tx and Rx are buffered and are either 16 to 64 depending on the amount of target RAM available. Note that I have never used Arduino; all I know is what I researched for this question.  I urge you to take a look at the source yourself: http://arduino.googlecode.com/files/arduino-1.0-src.tar.gz

Comment: BTW: The receive buffer will only hold 63 bytes max. Same must be true for the transmit buffer, otherwise the controller code wouldn't crash with 64 bytes and run properly with 63. So 63 is safe, 64 is not. Probably same for 15 vs. 16 for smaller controllers.

Comment: @Jippie: Again, looking at the code, the `store_char()` function in the ring buffer implementation does not store a character if incrementing the head index will make it equal to the tail index, which does indeed mean that only *n*-1 characters can be stored in a buffer of length *n*. To avoid that would require an additional count variable to allow an empty and full buffer to be distinguished (because in both cases head==tail). So you are right 63 characters is the maximum.

Comment: Thnx Clifford, my C++ knowledge is not very good. I did look at the source code and it doesn't look too complex, but I'm doing my first C++ project ever (other than making an LED flash). Also I just wanted to note the 15/63 issue for future reference.

Answer (score 6):

[The release notes](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ReleaseNotes) for 1.0 tell you:

- Serial transmission is now asynchronous - that is, calls to
  Serial.print(), etc. add data to an outgoing buffer which is transmitted
  in the background. Also, the Serial.flush() command has been repurposed
  to wait for outgoing data to be transmitted, rather than dropping
  received incoming data.

Therefore your code worked before 1.0, because `HardwareSerial::write(uint8_t)` (which is the foundation for all output) had no buffer and returned only after the byte has been transmitted.

I find it astonishing, that [the reference page](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Write) for `Serial` does not mention this behaviour.

Comment: That is an interesting find, I need to check that in more detail. Thnx

Comment: Good spot.  I downloaded the source to confirm my hypothesis and added to my answer accordingly.